# Android : Emulator doesn't launch

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to create a simple app. I created a new AVD. I launched it. I have been waiting for an hour, but the emulator shows only ANDROID. I am stuck. Can someone please help.

The image of how it is for an hour[image: stuck] Please don't mark duplicate. I searched and tried as much I can.

Is there anything I am doing wrong ? Help, please !!

My emulator creation[image: emulator creation]

I again launched the AVD and got this log. I think someone can definitely find the mistake that I am doing from this.

Creating filesystem with parameters:

```
ERROR: couldn't get path to resize2fs binary


    Size: 576716800
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7040
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 2200
    Label: 
    Blocks: 140800
    Block groups: 5
    Reserved block group size: 39


Created filesystem with 11/35200 inodes and 4536/140800 blocks  
Creating filesystem with parameters:


    Size: 69206016
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 4224
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 1024
    Label: 
    Blocks: 16896
    Block groups: 1
    Reserved block group size: 7  
Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks  
emulator: device fd:780  

HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode  

emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.


emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 1024 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.  


creating window 23 46 193 322  
emulator: UpdateCheck: current version '24.4.0', last version '24.4.0'
```

Comment: I have so many logs. Its been running for an hour

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or eclipse??

Comment: @PratibhaS Android studio 1.4

Comment: Can you check by closing your Android Studio and restarting once again

Comment: @PratibhaS I have tried restarting android studio. I created a new emulator . Waited for an hour also.

Comment: Please paste your logs , the log which u see as soon as you launch your AVD.

Comment: Okay. You mean the logs that is shown in logcat ??

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ram allocated to avd is exceeding ram allocated to HAXM. Either increase RAM of HAXM( not a good idea if you have 4 GB ram on your PC) or decrease ram of your AVD to match 1024 mb or lower.

I suggest creating emulator for some old device config  like nexus s and using X86 images .

Post further queries if this dose not work.

Answer (score 0):

Open you AVD Manager and edit your device and check the CPU you have selected. Try using Intel Atom.

Also, Have you installed HAXM?

Comment: Yes. I deleted the emulator, created a new one and used Intel Atom

Comment: Have you installed HAXM?

Comment: yes i have installed. And I have added an image that shows emulator config.

Comment: Try enabling Host GPU

Answer (score 0):

Can't really tell without knowing your **AVD** settings or your **PC** configurations but if I were to take a guess, the major reason could be the ***amount of RAM*** you have supplied to your AVD or Android Studio. If the amount of RAM you've specified for the AVD is too low, the loading of the OS would take time just like a PC with low RAM takes longer to boot.

Comment: I have added an image of the emulator creation. And my pc RAM is 4GB

Comment: Ok, your AVD seems to have all the required values. Give it one last by enabling Host GPU. Also, if that fails, add the logs ... someone might be able to help you using those

Answer (score 0):

please check that your emulator's API level is <= android:minSdkVersion in your manifest . Please try to launch another AVD by clicking **Tools > Android > AVD Manager**.

Comment: Sorry I am new to android.How to check android:minSdkVersion ?

Comment: I didn't know how to check androi:minSdkVersion but i tried launching another AVD as you said and i have edited my question with those logs. Hope you will find my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i have run a virtual machine with Windows,shut down this machine and solve your problem whit emulator the Android.
**Good Luck**